# How to fix jerking bugs sticky table on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made my table based on the jquery floatthead plugin. The table has a sticky head. And on the mobile below appears table scrolling and the first column becomes sticky. But on real devices it works crookedly. The table header twitches. The first column, too. How to fix these bugs?

My table:
https://codepen.io/malinosky/pen/vrBgMP

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var table = $(".b-table");
  table.floatThead({ position: "absolute", top: 0 });

  var tableWraps = $(".table-responsive");

  tableWraps.each(function() {
    var tableWrap = $(this);
    var headFirstColumn = tableWrap.find("td:first-child");

    tableWrap.on("scroll", function() {
      headFirstColumn.css("left", this.scrollLeft);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `absolute` position. Instead do this: 

`table.floatThead({ position: "fixed", top: 0 });`

Absolute position is better for internal scrolling tables. Fixed position is better for page scrolling. The plugin sets these things for you, if you don't provide a value.

With a fixed position setting the table's position is 'fixed' while you scroll the page which eliminates the jerkiness.